# eclipse-plugin for Hadoop 2.4.1 for Mapreduce programing

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I installed hadoop 2.4.1 on centos (on VMware) and Eclips on windows 8.1 .

How do I configure Eclips for Hadoop for writing mapreduce programing in Eclips?

In other words, how i do add plugins Hadoop to Eclips?

Comment: very tanx, i am familiar with production jar file in Eclips Environment. I would like to implement the Map and Reduce function in Eclips Environment for Apriori algorithm, But Eclipse detection errors for INTWritable ,... .   
     
Meanwhile, I'm going to run the fp-growth algorithm in the Eclipse environment. In your opinion , i run that algorithm in Eclips or on Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to articulate your question and provide more details.
Also it seems that you are not familiar with Hadoop cluster.
Based on your current configuration I recommend 2 scenarios:

1. You need a running Hadoop instance on your windows machine if you want to use eclipse to directly run jobs on Hadoop. So install Hadoop on windows instead of Centos.
2. If you want to run Hadoop on Centos you can write your code on eclipse, then create a jar file and deploy the jar file on Hadoop cluster. you can use this tutorial for this scnario:
   http://gerrymcnicol.com/index.php/2014/01/02/hadoop-and-cassandra-part-5-deploying-an-eclipse-mapreduce-project-to-hadoop/

Comment: 1. This link you shared is explaining configuring Hadoop when you want to change Hadoop code. As far as I understand you want to run a MapReduce job not changing Hadoop code. is that correct?

Comment: 2.please put your notes as comment on your question, not answering your own question

Comment: 3. what does this means? "but I am familiar with the eclips of the jar file."

Comment: 4.I'm pretty sure with providing a clear vision of problem we can find the solution. so please be patient and answer my questions

Comment: As far as I know, you should use Mahout for running FP-growth. So you write your code on eclipse and when you want to deploy it you should make sure that in your Hadoop cluster you have loaded the Mahout libraries too.

Answer (score 0):

**tanx mr arjomandi , but
I am familiar with the eclips of the jar file.i have this problem that when i write java code with mapreduce format in Eclips, diagnostic error like INTWritable error.  With search in the internet ,I see that I must import plugin-hadoop to eclips.On the other hand , plugin related to hadoop 2. 4. 1 is not present in the Internet. 
I hope i mean well i expressed.
on the site that have explanations, i dont know in terms like $[HOME] and set path. like below link :
How-to: Configure Eclipse for Hadoop Contributions
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.cloudera.com%2Fblog%2F2013%2F05%2Fhow-to-configure-eclipse-for-hadoop-contributions%2F&ei=a7qEVI_bKofaOP2UgagF&usg=AFQjCNE8fDET6uodlI86dKRLgOBbfauOqA&bvm=bv.80642063,d.ZWU**

Comment: very tanx, i am familiar with production jar file in Eclips Environment. I would like to implement the Map and Reduce function in Eclips Environment for Apriori  algorithm, But Eclipse detection errors for INTWritable ,... .

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm going to run the fp-growth algorithm in the Eclipse environment. In your opinion , i run that algorithm in Eclips or on Hadoop?